# IntelliJ terminal setup

Tags: windows-7, intellij-idea, gradle

I used to run gradle test via IntelliJ terminal with following command,

`>gradle test` Accidentally I deleted my windows path environmental variable in my windows 7 machine.

After this when I run above command I get below error

```
'gradle' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
```

What should I add in `path environmental variable` to get this run again

```
IntelliJ version 13.0.3
```

I added all java and gradle path under env. variable (I can run test via cygwin with above command)
Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This issue was resolved after restarting the windows. Because after adding path to the env variable and restart `IntelliJ` was not enough.

I should have done this before posting the question.

Please bear with me if any convenience caused.

Cheers